# color pixel count with GraphicsMagick

Tags: pixel, graphicsmagick

I need to count pixels in an image that are not background color.
I am calling this from PHP (it's from ImageMagick):

```
gm convert test.png -fill black +opaque "rgb(255,255,255)" -fill white -opaque "rgb(255,255,255)" -print "pixels = %[fx:w*h*mean]\n"
```

But it does not give any result, nothing.
I tried using histogram instead:

```
gm convert test.png -define histogram:unique-colors=true -format %c histogram:info.txt
```

That works, but gives values for every color and more details, I just need a single number please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got a couple of issues here. You seem to be trying to mix GraphicsMagick with ImageMagick when they are not the same thing.

Firstly, GraphicsMagick does not have the `+opaque` operator that ImageMagick has.

Secondly, it doesn't have the `-fx` operator that ImageMagick has for doing maths.

I would suggest you move to, the more powerful, ImageMagick. Then it will work as you expect:

```
# Create a test image
convert -size 200x200 xc:black xc:white xc:red +append image.png
```

[image]

```
# Count the white pixels
convert image.png -fill black +opaque "rgb(255,255,255)" -print "pixels = %[fx:w*h*mean]\n" nul:
pixels = 40000
```

If you really, really must do it with GraphicsMagick, I can only suggest the following - which is heavily based on @GlennRanders-Pehrson answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27318195/2836621):

```
gm convert image.png +matte -matte -transparent white -operator matte negate 1 result.png

gm identify -verbose result.png | grep -EA5 "Opacity:|Geometry:" | grep -E "Mean|Geometry"
  Geometry: 600x200
  Mean:                    43690.00 (0.6667)
  Mean:                    43690.00 (0.6667)
```

And your answer will be:

```
600 * 200 * (1 - 0.667)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Indeed, I have just tried to use a solution for ImageMagick, but I do have to stick to GraphicsMagick. I don't understand the command "-define histogram:unique-colors=true" either and couldn't find any info yet ...

Comment: That setting doesn't appear to make any difference.